# The solution to this joint distribution problem is too terse for me to understand.

Tags: probability, random-variables

I was wondering if I could get clarification on the following problem:

[image]

We know that $\sum_x\sum_y f(x, y) = 1$. Then $4\theta_1 + 6\theta_2 = 1$.

I understand that $P[X = 1] = ... = P[Y = 4] = 2\theta_1 + 3\theta_2$, but I do not know how the author reaches the conclusion $2\theta_1 + 3\theta_2 = \frac{1}{2}$. If we divide the equation $4\theta_1 + 6\theta_2 = 1$ by 2, we arrive at this. Is that what the author did?

I understand that $P[X = 1, Y = 2] = P[X = 1]\cdot P[Y = 2]$, but I do not know how $P[X = 1]\cdot P[Y = 2] = \frac{1}{4} = \theta_1 + \theta_2$ is reached. I got $P[X = 1]\cdot P[Y = 2] = (2\theta_1 + 3\theta_2)(2\theta_1 + 3\theta_2) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$. But I don't know how the conclusion that $\frac{1}{4} = \theta_1 + \theta_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the explanation is terse.

You correctly understand why you can say $4\theta_1 + 6\theta_2 = 1,$
and the formula $2\theta_1 + 3\theta_2 = \frac12$ appears to be, as you say,
just dividing that formula by $2$.

But another motivation for writing
the formula that way is that the sum of probabilities in a single
column of the joint probability table is $2\theta_1 + 3\theta_2$
(and this also turns out to be the sum of probabilities in one row of the table).
Hence $P(X=1) = 2\theta_1 + 3\theta_2,$
but also $P(Y=2) = 2\theta_1 + 3\theta_2.$
So it is interesting that $2\theta_1 + 3\theta_2 = \frac12$,
because now we know $P(X=1)=\frac12$ and $P(Y=2)=\frac12$.
And from those two facts we know $P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=2)=\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac14$.

The fact that $P(X=1,Y=2)=\theta_1 + \theta_2$ is something we can just
read from the upper left-hand entry in the joint probability table.
Combining all this with the fact that (as you know)
$P(X=1,Y=2)=P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=2)$ (because the events are independent),
and we can put all these equal things together in one long chain of
equations, as the solution did:
$$P(X=1,Y=2)=P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=2)=\frac14=\theta_1 + \theta_2.$$
The trick is somehow to remember which things in
that chain of equations were originally found equal to each other in what order.
Possibly this would have been a bit easier to see if they had put
$\theta_1 + \theta_2$ at the left end of this chain of equations
rather than at the far right end.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense now. Was there any point to the question stating the additional constraints to $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$? As far as I can tell, we never used them in the problem.

Comment: I wonder about that too. I notice that the assumption of independence forces $\theta_1$ to its maximum constrained value and $\theta_2$ to its minimum; also, the given minimum of $\theta_1$ is not achievable. Maybe  this problem was adapted from a more general one where the constraints played a larger role than here (where the role they play is that they barely avoid _preventing_ a solution).